# Setting up a date field to require an end date

Tags: 7, entities

I'm attempting to create a custom content type for a module via hook_install. When I create a date type (from Date module), I want it to require an end date (there's a checkbox when you're setting up the field via the gui). This is the settings array for the field:

```
'settings' => array(
    'enddate_get' => 1,
    'enddate_required' => 1,
),
```

This isn't working (the widget is still only asking for one date), so I'm guess that I have the wrong settings. Does anyone know how to properly set this up?

Comment: Is that D6 or D7?

Comment: Looks tagged as D7 to me.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it after this comment was posted. I thought I replied also.... must not have

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to setup the requirement on the form you are building for the custom content type so you would add this to the date_end form entry:

```
$form['CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE']['DATE_END'] = array(
...
  '#required' => TRUE,
...
),
```